# URL Encoding with httpclient

Tags: java, encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a list of URLs which I need to get the content of.
The URL is with special characters and thus needs to be encoded.
I use Commons HtpClient to get the content.

when I use:

```
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(url);
```

I get a " Invalid "illegal escape character" exception.
when I use

```
 GetMethod get = new GetMethod();
 get.setURI(new URI(url.toString(), false, "UTF-8"));
```

I get 404 when trying to get the page, because  a space is turned to `%2520` instead of just `%20`.

I've seen many posts about this problem, and most of them advice to build the URI part by part. The problem is that it's a given list of URLs, not a one that I can handle manually.

Any other solution for this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Do you get the two errors for the same URL (or does the first method work for some, and the second for others)?

Comment: I get the two errors on the same URL.

Comment: @user1251654 did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

What if you create a new URL object from it's string like `URL urlObject = new URL(url)`, then do `urlObject.getQuery()` and `urlObject.getPath()` to split it right, parse the Query Params into a List or a Map or something and do something like:

**EDIT:** I just found out that HttpClient Library has a `URLEncodedUtils.parse()` method which you can use easily with the code provided below. I'll edit it to fit, however is untested.

With Apache HttpClient it would be something like:

```
URI urlObject = new URI(url,"UTF-8");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<NameValuePair> formparams = URLEncodedUtils.parse(urlObject,"UTF-8");
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlObject.getPath());
httppost.setEntity(entity);
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity entity2 = response.getEntity();
```

With Java URLConnection it would be something like:

```
    // Iterate over query params from urlObject.getQuery() like
while(en.hasMoreElements()){
    String paramName  = (String)en.nextElement(); // Iterator over yourListOfKeys
    String paramValue = yourMapOfValues.get(paramName); // replace yourMapOfNameValues
    str = str + "&" + paramName + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramValue);
}
try{
    URL u = new URL(urlObject.getPath()); //here's the url path from your urlObject
    URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
    uc.setDoOutput(true);
    uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
    pw.println(str);
    pw.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    String res = in.readLine();
    in.close();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detaild answerr. I this that hte basic problem is that I cant find a java encoder that workd with httpclient whcih will encode the "right" way. the http-client encode encodes with "%25" many charachters

Comment: @user1251654 did you try the `URLEncodedUtils` (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) I mentioned in my answer? doesn't it works right with HttpClient?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manipulate with request URIs it is strongly advisable to use `URIBuilder` shipped with Apache HttpClient.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class. 
I used it in an exact scenario and it worked just fine for me.  
What I did is to use the URL class, to get the part that comes after the host
 (for example - at www.bla.com/mystuff/bla.jpg this would be  "mystuff/bla.jpg" - you should URLEncode only this part, and then consturct the URL again. 
 
For example, if the orignal string is "http://www.bla.com/mystuff/bla foo.jpg" then: 
Encode - "mystuff/bla foo.jpg" and get "mystuff/bla%20foo.jpg" and then attach this to the host and protocol parts: 
"http://www.bla.com/mystuff/bla%20foo.jpg" 
I hope this helps

Comment: when I use URLEncoder, it encoded the whole URL, and then it thrwos an excpetion on executeMethod() becuase host is null.

Comment: You don't need to encode the entire URL. My problem was with an image that served as a profile picture of someone on Twitter. What I did is encode the part that comes the host.

Comment: URLEncoder is not for encoding URLs, despite the name. It is for encoding html mime attachments.

Answer (score -1):

try it out

```
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(url.replace(" ","%20")).toASCIIString());
```

Comment: this will only encode spaces. What about slashes or other special characters? So this won't work in all cases.